# Rails route question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a login form (/user).
And methods:
-authenticate
-logout

And one view index.html.erb, it contains the login form, authenticate is work fine, but I think I have problems with routing.
Can you give me a sample route?
My router looks like:
map.logout 'logout', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'destroy'
 map.login 'login', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'new'
In sessions control have destroy method, but when I type /logout it's say: Missing template session/destroy.erb in view path app/view

Comment: My controller looks like:
 map.logout 'logout', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'destroy'   
  map.login 'login', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'new'                      

                                                                                                            In sessions control have destroy method, but when I type /logout it's say: Missing template session/destroy.erb in view path app/views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All routing system is explain on guides :

http://guides.rubyonrails.org

This one in particular : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

A sample route in Rails 3

```
match '/user(/index)' => 'users#index'
```

It would be helpful if you could clarify the issue you're having (and post relevant code).